# Keras evaluate_generator accuracy high, but accuracy of each class is low

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, classification

I am using Keras **ImageDataGenerator** to load and train a model on 101-food-dataset. I am using the **same** split for **validation** and **test**. I also use **sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix** to calculate accuracy for each class.

After training, when I use **evaluate_generator**, I get high accuracy. But the accuracy of individual classes is very low. What mistake am I making?

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
  train_data_dir,
  target_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size,
  class_mode='categorical',
  subset='training')

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
  train_data_dir,
  target_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size,
  class_mode='categorical',
  subset='validation')

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // batch_size,
                validation_data=validation_generator,
                validation_steps=validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
                epochs=epochs,
                verbose=1,
                callbacks=[csv_logger, checkpointer])

loss, acc = model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator, steps=3, verbose=0)
print('loss: ', loss, 'accuracy: ', acc) # loss:  0.4534463981787364 accuracy:  0.8333333

y_pred = model.predict_generator(validation_generator)
y_pred = np.array([np.argmax(x) for x in y_pred])
y_test = validation_generator.classes

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
cm.diagonal()
acc_each_class = cm.diagonal()

print('accuracy of each class: \n')
for i in range(len(labels)):
  print(labels[i], ' : ', acc_each_class[i])
print('\n')

'''
accuracy of each class: 

cannoli  :  0.085
dumplings  :  0.065
edamame  :  0.1
falafel  :  0.125
french_fries  :  0.12
grilled_cheese_sandwich  :  0.13
hot_dog  :  0.075
seaweed_salad  :  0.085
tacos  :  0.105
takoyaki  :  0.135
'''
```

Comment: why do you want the accuracy of class to be high when the overall accuracy is high aren't you getting the right answer ?

Comment: I suspect that my code has bugs. When the overall accuracy is high, shouldn't each class show also high accuracy? Aren't they related to each other?

Comment: they are related, both should be high, although sometimes there is some coding error with one of the class which will make that particular class predict the accuracy wrong not all the class

Comment: So where is my coding error?

Comment: It seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6499).

Comment: Try setting ```shuffle=False``` and fixed ```seed``` value in ```flow_from_directory```, as your ```y_pred``` and ```y_true``` might have been shuffled inconsistently.

Comment: Tested, the same issue. Continued the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59666167/keras-evaluate-generator-accuracy-and-scikit-learn-accuracy-score-inconsistent) since the problem is somewhere else I guess

Answer (score 0):

I investigated your issue I think this is due to that you have more than one worker opening the files numerous of times, to fix this issue make sure to set :

**shuffle = false**

**pickle_safe = True**

**workers = 1**

or only evaluate your model via evaluate_generator or predict_generator :

```
validation_generator2 = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary', shuffle=False)

score = model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator, nb_validation_samples/batch_size, workers=12)

scores = model.predict_generator(validation_generator2, nb_validation_samples/batch_size, workers=12)
```

Comment: Not working. BTW, there is no `pickle_safe` att. anymore

Comment: Continued the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59666167/keras-evaluate-generator-accuracy-and-scikit-learn-accuracy-score-inconsistent) since the problem is somewhere else I guess