# Keras evaluate_generator accuracy and scikit learn accuracy_score inconsistent

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I am using Keras ImageDataGenerator class to load, train and predict. I had tried the solutions [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6499), but still have the issue. I am not sure if I have the same issue as mentioned [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6499). I guess my `y_pred` and `y_test` are not correctly mapped to each other.

```py
validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation',
    shuffle='False')

validation_generator2 = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation',
    shuffle='False')

loss, acc = model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator,
                                     steps=math.ceil(validation_generator.samples / batch_size),
                                     verbose=0,
                                     workers=1)

y_pred = model.predict_generator(validation_generator2,
                                 steps=math.ceil(validation_generator2.samples / batch_size),
                                 verbose=0,
                                 workers=1)

y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
y_test = validation_generator2.classes[validation_generator2.index_array]

print('loss: ', loss, 'accuracy: ', acc) # loss:  0.47286026436090467 accuracy:  0.864
print('accuracy_score: ', accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)) # accuracy_score:  0.095
```

The `evaluate_generator` from Keras and `accuracy_score` from scikit learn gives different accuracy. And of course this gave me wrong confusion matrix when I use `confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)` from scikit learn. What mistake am I making? (by `y_test` I mean `y_true`)

Update:
To show that `y_test` and `y_pred` are inconsistent, I am printing the accuracy of each class.

```py
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
cm.diagonal()
acc_each_class = cm.diagonal()

print('accuracy of each class: \n')
for i in range(len(labels)):
  print(labels[i], ' : ', acc_each_class[i])
print('\n')

'''
accuracy of each class: 

cannoli  :  0.085
dumplings  :  0.065
edamame  :  0.1
falafel  :  0.125
french_fries  :  0.12
grilled_cheese_sandwich  :  0.13
hot_dog  :  0.075
seaweed_salad  :  0.085
tacos  :  0.105
takoyaki  :  0.135
```

As can be seen, the accuracy of each class are too low.

Update2: How I trained the model, may help

```py
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training')

    validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation',
    shuffle='False')

    validation_generator2 = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation',
    shuffle='False')

    loss = CategoricalCrossentropy()

    model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=lr, momentum=momentum),
                  loss=loss,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // batch_size,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    validation_steps=validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=[csv_logger, checkpointer],
                    workers=12)
```

Answer (score 0):

My first impression is that you have trained two different models. A lot of models have some sort of "random" element in them (how to initialise the weights in a neural network for example) which automatically results in a slightly different classifier as well. 
The accuracy you state was made by keras is for the model  "validation_generator", while the sklearn accuracy is on "validation_generator2". You could try this: (please note that I have not tried this block of code)

```
validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation',
    shuffle='False')

loss, acc = model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator,
                                     steps=math.ceil(validation_generator.samples / batch_size),
                                     verbose=0,
                                     workers=1)

y_pred = model.predict_generator(validation_generator,
                                 steps=math.ceil(validation_generator.samples / batch_size),
                                 verbose=0,
                                 workers=1)

y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
y_test = validation_generator.classes[validation_generator.index_array]

print('loss: ', loss, 'accuracy: ', acc) # loss:  0.47286026436090467 accuracy:  0.864
print('accuracy_score: ', accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)) # accuracy_score:  0.095
```

Comment: Tested. the same issue

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be using the same generator for both evaluate_generator and predict_generator as stated by San.

Secondly, I think the accuracy between sklearn and keras are not exactly the same as stated in the [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score) accuracy_score in case of multiclass is really the jaccard score.

This link shows the difference:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255465/accuracy-vs-jaccard-for-multiclass-problem

Comment: The confusion matrix is also wrong. This shows that the y_test and y_pred are not consistent. The sklearn accuracy is not important for me.

Comment: That's right, can you also show how you train your model (especially which loss you use?)

Comment: I edited the question and added the training code. I should mention that I had first trained the model, saved it, and load it later for doing prediction.

Comment: While training did the val accuracy were consistent with the evaluate_generator accuracy? I'm suspecting that predict_generator may mess with the labels

Comment: Yes yes, this shows that the training is done correctly.

Comment: I would try using the same code as San specified (with only one generator), and reset it using validation_generator.reset(). Also you wrote shuffle='False', this should be shuffle=False, as 'False' in python is a char and will be seen as True.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset the validation generator before calling model.predict_generator:

```
loss, acc = model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator,
                                     steps=math.ceil(validation_generator.samples / batch_size),
                                     verbose=0,
                                     workers=1)
validation_generator2.reset()
_pred = model.predict_generator(validation_generator2,
                                 steps=math.ceil(validation_generator2.samples / batch_size),
                                 verbose=0,
                                 workers=1)
```

Comment: Why should you reset it?